# NHibernate mapping class

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am new in NHibernate and need help. I have two classes:

```
class Pop3
{
    public virtual long Id { set; get; }
    public virtual string HostName { set; get; }
    public virtual int Port { set; get; }
    public virtual bool UseSsl { set; get; }
}

class Email
{
    public virtual long Id { set; get; }
    public virtual string UserName { set; get; }
    public virtual string Password { set; get; }
    public virtual Pop3 Host { set; get; }
}
```

I need to map them to NHibernate (uses Sqlite).
That is easy with Pop3 class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                  assembly="TestAsm"
                  namespace="TestAsm.Entity.Mail">

  <class name="Pop3" table="pop3hosts">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="HostName" />
    <property name="Port" />
    <property name="UseSsl" />
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

But how can I map Email class contains Pop3 class as property?
My be i need to set Pop3.Id in Host property? But I think it is wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mapping belongs to the most basic, typical and well documented, I would say

An example, where the `Pop3` class is mapped with `many-to-one` over the column `Pop3Id`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                  assembly="TestAsm"
                  namespace="TestAsm.Entity.Mail">

  <class name="Email" table="email_table">
    <id name="Id" generator="identity" />

    <property name="UserName" />
    <property name="Password" />

    <many-to-one name="Host" column="Pop3Id" class="Pop3 " />

  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Please check the [Chapter 21. Example: Parent/Child](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#example-parentchild)

Comment: Do I need to set namespace in class attribute if class is in different name space like `class="TestAsm.Net.Pop3"`?

Comment: Great if that helped ;) `namespace` attribute on the class element is an abbrev, so if all referenced entities (many-to-one) are in the same ns ... no need to declare it again. but if class is in different, we have to provide its name with namespace. Enjoy NHibernate